# Not a git repository: '.git' error in subfolder

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

This error started cropping up since I upgraded git (Im on version 2.8.1).

I can duplicate this in any repository (github or bitbucket). Essentially if a repo has a sub directory git command fails to recognize it as a valid git repo.

[image]

The `mus` folder content:

```
➜  shinylang git:(master) ls -la mus
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 sandeep  staff   102 Jun  7 10:32 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 sandeep  staff   170 Jun  7 10:32 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 sandeep  staff  3523 Jun  7 10:32 compiler.js
```

Here's the test github repo https://github.com/csandeep/shinylang

My .gitconfig

```
[user]
    email = sandeep@##########
    name = Sandeep Chayapathi

[alias]
        co = checkout
        st = status
[core]
    excludesfile = /Users/sandeep/.gitignore_global
    editor = mate -wl1
    trustctime = false
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = /Users/sandeep/Applications/Perforce/p4merge.app/Contents/MacOS/p4merge \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
    path = 
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = /Users/sandeep/Applications/Perforce/p4merge.app/Contents/MacOS/p4merge \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"
    trustExitCode = true
[merge]
    conflictstyle = diff3
    tool = sourcetree
[rerere]
    enabled = false
[mergetool "Kaleidoscope"]
    cmd = ksdiff --merge --output \"$MERGED\" --base \"$BASE\" -- \"$LOCAL\" --snapshot \"$REMOTE\" --snapshot
    trustexitcode = true
[difftool "Kaleidoscope"]
    cmd = ksdiff --partial-changeset --relative-path \"$MERGED\" -- \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[mergetool "p4mergetool"]
    cmd = /Users/sandeep/Applications/Perforce/p4merge.app/Contents/Resources/launchp4merge \"$PWD/$BASE\" \"$PWD/$REMOTE\" \"$PWD/$LOCAL\" \"$PWD/$MERGED\"
    trustExitCode = false
[difftool "p4mergetool"]
    cmd = /Users/sandeep/Applications/Perforce/p4merge.app/Contents/Resources/launchp4merge \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
    keepBackup = false
    trustExitCode = false
[diff]

[mergetool "extMerge"]
    cmd = extMerge \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"
[diff]
    guitool = extDiff
[filter "media"]
    required = true
    clean = git media clean %f
    smudge = git media smudge %f
[filter "hawser"]
    clean = git hawser clean %f
    smudge = git hawser smudge %f
    required = true
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge %f
    required = true
```

Note: removing the `.gitignore` file solved this issue. Weirdly adding it back no longer triggers this issue. All in all one of the weirdest bugs I have seen.

Comment: Can you please show `ls -l` inside `mus`?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I have edited the question with the content of the folder. I can duplicate this on a private repo that has mutliple directories and it was working all along till I upgraded Xcode.

Comment: That is correct. There is no git repo inside mus. You can only call `git status` from the root folder of the app, where `.git` is

Comment: I cloned the repo and can do a `git status` successfully from within the 'mus' dir. If a directory is added to the project (like mus), then git commands should work inside it. If it were a symlink to another dir on your system, then you likely would not get results after a `cd` into it.

Comment: @saliens No -- you can run git status from any project subdir, you don't need to be in the repo's root.

Comment: I'm running 2.7.4, but I don't see why something like this would change in 2.8.1. Is there something in your `~/.gitconfig` that might be throwing it off? Or an alias for your command line which is getting in the way?

Comment: Your example works fine for me as well. There's nothing wrong with the repo. I suspect your git config is borked.

Comment: Please paste your `~/.gitconfig` in your post. If there's a system-level config file, please paste that, too.

Comment: @tniles09 Heh was thinking the same thing. Sandeep, I would suggest you temporarily remove your ~/.gitconfig and then run the git status command via its full path, like `/usr/bin/git status` or whatever. That will ensure you're not running any aliases or shell functions.

Comment: dang the `.gitconfig` was the culprit, going update the question with my copy of the gitconfig.

Comment: Hmmm... I can't say that I see anything obvious in your config file That would cause this. Did you try removing it, and did that fix the problem? Maybe your 'excludesfile' has a 'mus' (or matching regex) in it? Also, did you try @AlexHowansky's suggestion of running the native command (i.e. `/usr/bin/git status`)?

Comment: Removing the .gitconfig solved it! Also weirdly adding back the exact config no longer triggers this issue. Definitely something in the config file, will explore a bit later as this solves the immediate issue.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no `mus/.git` then `mus` itself isn't a git repo. You can `git add mus` to add `mus` and its contents to the `shinylang` repo, or run `git init` inside `mus` to initialize it as a separate repo, but submodules are tricky and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Its already added to the repo which is what is puzzling. More than `git status` I'm not able to run `git diff` or any git commands inside these directories which is more frustrating.

Comment: This is wrong. You can run git status from any folder under the project root regardless of whether it's tracked in the repository.